# Recycler view showing empty list on gradle 7 and above

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, signed, android-gradle-7.0

**I am using below things**

- In built recycler view
- Volley
- MVP architecture with parcelable classes
- Gradle 4.0.2 with 6.7.1 wrapper and JDK 8.1
- No extra rules in proguard
- APP IS WORKING FOR ABOVE CONFIG (RELEASE APK)

**App is not working after the gradle is upgraded to 7.2.1 and 7.3.3 in wrapper**

- It shows blank list
- API is called, response comes and adapter also executes but recycler view is empty
- App is working for unsinged apk
- **APP IS NOT WORKING ONLY FOR SINGED APK CASE WITH PROGUARD WITH GRADLE 7 & ABOVE**